# Can't use/install a Quarto extension (created by myself) from Github

Tags: r, github, rstudio, quarto, reveal.js

I am relatively new to Quarto ans GitHub and I am having a problem in using/installing a Quarto extension I have developed. It is a Revealjs template.
To create it, I have followed the instructions provided in the [Quarto official documentation](https://quarto.org/docs/extensions/formats.html#quick-start).
I created the extension using the `quarto create` command in the shell. I then pushed all the files to a [GitHub repo](https://github.com/giuliomela/rse_ppt/tree/master). The extension works fine when I render the template.qmd file from the root.
The problem arises when I try to use my new template in another R project. When I type `quarto use template giuliomela/rse_ppt` or `quarto add giuliomela/rse_ppt` I get the following message: `Extension not found in local or remote sources` as the repo was private, but it is indeed public.
I guess there is something wrong with my GitHub since I can use and install other Quarto extension without problem, such as Grant McDermott's [clean template](https://github.com/grantmcdermott/quarto-revealjs-clean).
What am I doing wrong?

I am using R Studio

```markdown
RStudio 2023.06.0+421 "Mountain Hydrangea" 
Release (583b465ecc45e60ee9de085148cd2f9741cc5214, 2023-06-05) for windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
RStudio/2023.06.0+421 Chrome/110.0.5481.208 Electron/23.3.0 Safari/537.36
```

```markdown
R version 4.2.3 on Windows
```

I have installed the latest version of Quarto (`quarto-1.3.433-win.msi`)

I tried to create the Quarto extension following the official documentation very strictly. I even tried to insert in the _extension.yml file chunks of code from other working extensions to understand if the problem was at the GitHub or Quarto level.

Comment: `quarto add giuliomela/rse_ppt` will search for files in the `main` branch by default. Since your extension is in `master` branch, try the command, `quarto add giuliomela/rse_ppt@master`